# Storing already generated data in spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, spyder

I am new to python programming. I am using spyder to run my code. I have generated a very big data in python after 3 hours of computation. Now I want to save my data. One way of doing this is calling the `pickle.dump()` function, but in order to do this I have to run my program again and this will take another 3 hours. In what way I can store my data when data has already been generated in Spyder?

Answer (score 0):

What form does the data take? If it's a database in pandas, you can export it to a csv or xlsx

Comment: I have a very big BitVector.

Comment: Please respond.

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with BitVector, if you have a look through their documentation there may be something that could help https://pypi.org/project/BitVector/